# How to immediately disable access to a user that is soft-deleted or no longer enabled?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security, symfony5

In my application, users with the role `ROLE_ADMIN` are able to manually disable other user accounts, by setting `enabled` on the user account to false.

Using a [user checker](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_checkers.html), the user will not be able to log in the next time they try:

```
public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user)
{
    if (!$user->isEnabled()) {
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException(
            'Account is not enabled.'
        );
    }
}
```

My issue with this, it only works when a user tries to log in. If a user is currently logged in (could also be using the remember-me-functionality), nothing happens until they logout.

Is there any way to immediately disable the user from making requests to routes it no longer should have access to, even when this user is currently logged in?

What I could do is check if the account is enabled for every route that requires this user access, like so:

```
if ($this->getUser()->isEnabled() === false) {
    throw new \Exception("Account disabled");
}
```

But this seems like a terrible solution because I would need this in many places.

Comment: Just add a [kernel request subscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber) and check there then redirect to the logout processor.  Voters are not appropriate for this.  The equatable interface is an interesting idea but probably will not work as desired.

Comment: @Cerad, just to clarify, you would check if a the user is disabled for every request and if so they are redirected to logout? Could this be done only for routes where user access is required?

Comment: Yep.  Every request is the easiest.  I don't know of any easy way to distinguish between protected and unprotected routes.  There is a lot of stuff that goes on behind the scenes for each request.  Adding one more listener is not going to impact performance.  And even if they accessed an unprotected route I would think you would still want to log them out if they are disabled.

Comment: @Cerad I'm not sure what you mean with "will not work as desired". I've successfully used EquatableInterface in production to force users to be logged out when an attribute changes. Is there a side-effect I'm not aware of?

Comment: @Pete If it works then great.  There is actually no need to compare the enabled values, a simple check of the current user would suffice.  And of course UserInterface does not know about the enabled property so might need a bit of type casting to keep the IDE happy.  I have just not seen it used that way before and we do get quite a few bits of untested code posted.  But again, if it works then it is worth giving it a try.

Comment: @Cerad Although it would be a lot easier to just check the `enabled` property of the current user, we *need* to compare them. If we would just `return $this->enabled` in `isEqualTo()` and `enabled` is false the user would be logged out every single time, instead of only being logged out when the property changes. Does that make sense? explaining things is hard :)

Comment: if ($user->enabled === false) return false; should do the trick.  And of course if you do want to compare then you need to ensure that the enabled property is serialized into the session.

Comment: @Cerad, I took your advice and created a listener and posted this below. Could you have a look? I am uncertain about whether this really is what you suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you implement the `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface` in your User class, [the User will be logged out when `isEqualTo()` returns false](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v4.4.7/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/AbstractToken.php#L309).

```
class User implements Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface
{
    /* ... */

    public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->enabled !== $user->enabled) {
            // Forces the user to log in again if enabled 
            // changes from true to false or vice-versa.
            // This could be replaced by a more sophisticated comparison.
            return false;
        }

        // do a bunch of other checks, such as comparing the 
        // password hash: this will cause the user to be logged 
        // out when their password is changed.

        return true;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

[Relevant documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#understanding-how-users-are-refreshed-from-the-session)

Comment: This is a neat solution. I implementing this class together with the UserInterface and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

I followed Cerad's advice, and added a listener as can be seen below. However, for a better (built-in) solution, see Pete's answer.

```
namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class RequestListener
{

    private $security; // needed to get the user
    private $router; // needed to generate the logout-url

    public function __construct(Security $security, UrlGeneratorInterface $router) 
    {
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function __invoke(RequestEvent $event) : void
    {
        $user = $this->security->getUser();

        // Don't do anything if no user is logged in.
        if ($user === null) {
            return;
        }

        if ($user->isEnabled() === false) {
            // Generate the logout url based on the path name and redirect to it.
            $url = $this->router->generate('app_logout');
            $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep.  Pretty much what I had in mind.  Though the EquatableInterface answer would save you from creating a class assuming you can modify your User object.

Comment: I actually like this approach better than the EquatableInterface, since it is more versatile